# Refining my javascript REGEX to format a short-name

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a javascript regex to turn a string into a short-name (for use in clean URLs). I need it to:

- convert it to lowercase
- strip all "bad" characters
- trim all leading and trailing whitespace
- replace single and multiple spaces for a dash.

This is what I have so far (newlines added for readability):

```
clean_value = $(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]+/g,'')
              .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').replace(/ +(?= )/g,'-')
              .replace(/ /g, '-');
```

This does it but I KNOW there is a more efficient way to form these REGEXs... I am so bad with them and have spent an hour trying to figure out how to combine these as much as possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://www.regexpal.com is an excellent resource for testing REGEXs.  You test REGEXs live to see what matches etc..

Comment: @Eli Yes, I had that bookmarked... very useful. This daisy-chained approach works... but I'm trying to find a more elegant way of handling the formatting. Especially since the above code doesn't deal with multiple dashes in a row ie "my---project"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look too bad in my opinion. Better have a sequence of readable, manageable regexes than one all-purpose monster that nobody (including yourself) will understand a few weeks from now.

One suggestion:

```
clean_value = $(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]+/g,'')
              .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').replace(/ +/g,'-');
```

to make the last `replace()` do what you specified - convert one or more spaces into a single dash.

If you still have multiple dashes in a row that you want to reduce to a single one, you could add a

```
.replace(/-{2,}/, '-')
```

at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The part where you trim the whitespace is actually faster if you split it into two separate replaces. See: [Faster JavaScript Trim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript). Here's how I would recommend doing it:

```js
function clean(text) {
    return text.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s\s*$/,'').toLowerCase()
        .replace(/[^a-z0-9\-\s]+/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,'-');
}
```

Note that the order is important to avoid multiple dashes.